# Ubuntu hard disk mounted with no partitions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I have an Ubuntu system with 2 hard disks. When I type the `lsblk` the output is the following:

```
sdb      8:16   1   1.8T  0 disk /storage
sdc      8:32   1   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   1   1.8T  0 part
```

As you can see `/dev/sdb` has no partitions but I am actively using it to store files.

Then `/dev/sdc` was formatted with `fdisk` and it has a partition.

Is this normal that `/dev/sdb` has no partitions, and how can I achieve the same on `/dev/sdc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely possible to put a filesystem on the bare storage (i.e: not in a partition)... but that's not generally how you'd go about doing it.

Partition tables (either MBR or GPT) give you a little hint as to what is stored on a region of the disk (i.e: the partition type) - presenting regions of the disk without the need to worry about offsets, and removing the need to be careful about one logical region extending over another. They can also permit early boot code to be stored alongside filesystems and "*in the gaps*", though this is less common in modern desktop systems.

In Linux, the partition type can usually be determined by ["*magic*"](https://linux.die.net/man/5/magic) alone, and there is not hard requirement for partitions, as you can see... But Windows will likely not play well with this device, and may even prompt you to format it (eep!)

> Is this normal that `/dev/sdb` has no partitions, and how can I achieve the same on `/dev/sdc`?

It's not "*normal*", and I'd encourage you to stick with the partitioning you've got on `/dev/sdc`... not try to reproduce the "*partition-less*" setup you have on `/dev/sdb`.

However, if you particularly *want* to... then you can simply run `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc`, which will clobber the partition table and create an ext4 filesystem on the disk (not a partition)... You'll likely be warned that a partition table was found, but can easily proceed if you wish. Other `mkfs.*` commands exist for other filesystems, and as always, be prepared to loose anything on that disk!